# Remove a dropdown option once it's selected

Tags: sharepoint-server, jquery

I have a requirement that seeks to remove a sharepoint dropdown option if selected and when you click the save button the option selected needs to get removed from the dropdown menu.

here's my jquery code:

$(document).ready(function(){

```
removeItems();
```

});

function removeItems()
{

$("#ctl00_m_g_080195fc_7520_4906_a7d3_7f90b10d5b73_ctl00_toolBarTbl_RightRptControls_SaveButton2_ctl00_diidIOSaveItem").click(function(){

```
var selectedItem = $("#ctl00_m_g_080195fc_7520_4906_a7d3_7f90b10d5b73_ctl00_CustomFieldIterator1_ctl02_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_DropDownChoice option:selected").val();
alert(selectedItem+" is removed from the dropdown options.");
  $("#ctl00_m_g_080195fc_7520_4906_a7d3_7f90b10d5b73_ctl00_CustomFieldIterator1_ctl02_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_DropDownChoice option:selected").remove();

});
```

}

this seems to work when saving the form but when I load the form again the option loads again. Anyone with help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $("#ctl00_m_g_080195fc_7520_4906_a7d3_7f90b10d5b73_ctl00_CustomFieldIterator1_ctl02_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_DropDownChoice option:selected").remove();
```

Above line will only remove data from loaded DOM (Client browser).

To remove from SharePoint dropdown value,

```
var categoryField = cldList.get_fields().getByInternalNameOrTitle("Category");
var categoryChoiceField = context.castTo(categoryField, SP.FieldChoice);
context.load(categoryChoiceField);

context.executeQueryAsync(function () {
        var categoryChoices = categoryChoiceField.get_choices();

          //now your logic
          //var i=categoryChoices.indexOf(SelectedValue);
          //categoryChoices.splice(i, 1);
            categoryChoiceField.set_choices(categoryChoices);
            categoryChoiceField.updateAndPushChanges();
            context.executeQueryAsync(function () { }, function () { });

    }, function () { });
```

Comment: Hi Anil please provide a complete solution if you may, I'm not sure what to put in these functions that are parameters. I'm quite not new in SP

Comment: I finally got it to work. Thank you very much @Anil Pal

Comment: @Vusi85, Great. If above solution worked for you, mark it as answer. it could help others too.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue, too. I only had problems with one document file that I needed to deselect the dropdown value, so I did it directly in the browser's console. Here's what I did:

1. open the edit form where the dropdown is located.
2. F12 - get the element Id.
3. Go to "console" and run this, and then save the form:

   ```
        var removeValue = document.getElementById("Id from step 2");

        $(removeValue).val(" ");
   ```